# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when trying to populate responsive datatable using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I am trying to fill a responsive datatable with an AJAX request to a PHP script, the response is returned in JSON_encode format, I can see the response in the XHR requests:

```
["abc","def","ght","jkl"]
```

Here is the code I am using:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

```js
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
  responsive: true,
  "ajax": "search_autocomplete.php",
});
```

Here is the PHP script:

```
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $list[] =$row['name'];
  }     
  echo json_encode( $list );            
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to insert an array datasource, i.e not object literals, the source must be an array of arrays :

```js
[["abc"],["def"],["ght"],["jkl"]]
```

```js
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
  "ajax": {
    url: "search_autocomplete.php",
    dataSrc: ''
  }
});
```

```php
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $list[] = array($row['name']); //<----
  }     
  echo json_encode($list);            
}
```

---

That is also the case if you use Jonathans suggestion, `json_encode( array(data => $list))` - you would still need to wrap each item into an array, otherwise you get the `a`, `d`, `g` etc because dataTables access each string as the array it expects, each character is treated as an array item, data for a column.

```php
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $list[] = array($row['name']); //<----
  }     
  echo json_encode(array('data' => $list));
}
```

```js
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
  "ajax": "search_autocomplete.php"
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm thank you so much everyone for taking out time

Answer (score 1):

[When using just a string value](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#string), at least, DataTables's `ajax` option expects the response to be wrapped in another object:

> Note that DataTables expects the table data to be an array of items in the `data` parameter of the object ...
>
> ```
> {
>     "data": [
>         // row 1 data source,
>         // row 2 data source,
>         // etc
>     ]
> }
> ```

To get this, you can wrap the `$list` in another `array()` before encoding:

```
echo json_encode( array( data => $list ) );
```

Comment: thanks jonathan, my table received the data but only first alphabet is being populated in each row ex ["abc","def","ghi"]  row 1 displays only 'a' and second row 2 displays 'd'

Answer (score 0):

set Json Header

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $list );
```

Comment: do i need to define header because i can see the response in chrome developer tool

Answer (score 0):

You also should define variable `$list` before `while` loop. If it is not defined it return only last name.

```
$list = []
```

Comment: @njwin07 That is relevant code! Please post all the relevant code, without it people are just going to point to mistakes you actually didn't make and you will have a smaller chance of getting a good answer.